# How can I use a pre-trained ViT transformer model with the detectron2.modelling.ViT() function for object detection in Detectron2 along with configs?

Tags: python, pytorch, object-detection

How can I use a pre-trained ViT transformer model with the detectron2.modelling.ViT() function for object detection in Detectron2? Specifically, how can I integrate it with the DatasetMapper() function and configs(cfg)? Here is the code I have so far, any suggestions or help would be appreciated:

```
from detectron2.modeling import ViT

cfg = get_cfg()
cfg.DATASETS.TRAIN = ("data_detection_train",)
cfg.DATASETS.TEST = ()
cfg.DATALOADER.NUM_WORKERS = 2
cfg.MODEL = detectron2.modeling.ViT()
cfg.MODEL.WEIGHTS = "path/to/pretrained/weights.pth"
cfg.SOLVER.IMS_PER_BATCH = 2
cfg.SOLVER.BASE_LR = 0.006
cfg.SOLVER.MAX_ITER = 5000
cfg.MODEL.ROI_HEADS.BATCH_SIZE_PER_IMAGE = 512
cfg.MODEL.ROI_HEADS.NUM_CLASSES = 1
cfg.SOLVER.WEIGHT_DECAY = 0.0001

import detectron2.data.transforms as T
from detectron2.data import DatasetMapper
from detectron2.engine import DefaultTrainer
from detectron2.data.build import build_detection_train_loader

class MyTrainer(DefaultTrainer):
    @classmethod
    def build_train_loader(cls, cfg):
        augmentations = [
            T.RandomBrightness(0.9, 1.1),
            T.Resize((1600,900)),
            T.RandomFlip(prob=0.5, horizontal=True, vertical=False),
        ]
        mapper = DatasetMapper(cfg, is_train=True, augmentations=augmentations)
        return build_detection_train_loader(cfg, mapper=mapper)

trainer = MyTrainer(cfg) 
trainer.resume_or_load(resume=False)
trainer.train()
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Did you find an answer?